# Модифицировать массив объектов в новый частично склеивая по ходу

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Всем добрый день. Приходит ко мне веселая api со строгим количеством ключей, 720, каждый из которых состоит из набора значений:

```
0: object 
    x : 0
    y : 1
    z : 2
    time : "2017-03-09T07:00:00+03:00"
1: object 
    x : 0
    y : 1
    z : 2
    time : "2017-03-09T07:00:02+03:00"
... [720]
```

Мне необходимо последовательно от нулевого ключа склеивать каждые 5 в новый один.  В результате нужно получить 144 штуки, соответственно ключ `time` в каждом новом объекте должен быть `00:00 ;  01:00  ;  02:00`

Я загонял их forEach-ом и _.each и возможно я уже замылился, прошу помощи, направьте меня, иначе не вижу куда идти.

Пример:
что имеем:

```
0 [x:1, y:1, z:0, time: 00:00]
1 [x:2, y:2, z:4, time: 00:02]
2 [x:3, y:3, z:6, time: 00:04]
3 [x:0, y:0, z:0, time: 00:06]
4 [x:0, y:0, z:0, time: 00:08]
...720
```

на выходе получаем результат сложения первых пяти:

```
0 [x:6, y:6, z:10, time:00:00]
```

следующая итерация склеивает следующие 5 штук до конца

```
1 [x:number, y:number, z:number, time: 00:10]
2 [x:number, y:number, z:number, time: 00:20]
...144
```

Comment: 720/5 никак не 72. Непонятно как именно ты хочешь _склеивать_

Comment: Был не прав) 144 разумеется

Comment: зачем `time` делать строкой, если можно сделать массивом? Подразумевается, что значения `x,y,z` одинаковы для каждых пяти, или каким образом склеивать?

Comment: Добавь пример: например исходный массив из 10 элементов и соответствующий ему конечный массив из двух

Comment: Описал выше как должен работать механизм

Comment: ага, то есть сумма полей, и в поле time - первое значение из интервала

Comment: Да да, все так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ProcessEveryFive(input) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + 5) {
    var newItem = { x: input[i].x, y: input[i].y, z: input[i].z, time: input[i].time };
    for (var j = i + 1; j < i + 5; j++) {
      newItem.x = newItem.x + input[j].x;
      newItem.y = newItem.x + input[j].y;
      newItem.z = newItem.x + input[j].z;
    }
    result.push(newItem);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю примного! Вроде бы пока как часы!)